# Test virtual host configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm trying to test my virtual host configuration and the below command doesn't work... how can I test this?

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -S

-bash: /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd: No such file or directory
```

I got the command from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/

```
uname -r //returns the below
2.6.16.60-0.54.5-smp
```

Comment: Which distro are you using? Did you compile Apache from source or install binary version via package manager? You can find out the path with `which httpd` or `whereis httpd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have installed Apache through your distribution's package management system, it'll be installed in **/usr**, not **/usr/local**.

For Fedora/RHEL/CentOS, the main executable file will be **/usr/sbin/httpd**, while for Debian/Ubuntu you should try **/usr/sbin/apache2**.

For more information about distribution-specific layout you should check this URL: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout

Comment: on suse its - /usr/sbin/apache2ctl