# Trying to add another domain, but how can I debug to see what the problem is?

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2, debian-squeeze

I am using Debian 6 and I followed the Linode guides for setting up a LAMP server. http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/debian-6-squeeze

I have 1 working domain already, and I just added another one, and it doesn't work for some reason. I followed the steps on the guide to recreate another domain. The DNS for my domain is pointed the server, I even traced it. I don't know what is wrong, and I don't know how to debug it. Apache's documentation says use `/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -S`, but I don't have such a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using /usr/bin/apache2 -S

That's a start as it'll show you which virtualhosts are configured correctly.

Comment: I don't have such a directory/file

Comment: Then just type "apache2 -S"

Comment: I got: `apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}` - Trying to find solution now

Comment: Okay, the command works. It shows the 2 websites that I enabled, so it should be configured properly. However, I don't know what's the next step.

Comment: Did you reload Apache? As far as I know, the "apache2 -S" command just checks the config files. You need to reload Apache after you're done editing them. Try issuing "apache2 -k restart" and see what happens.

Comment: You could also use `apache2ctl -S`.
Also look for [Vladimir Blaskov](http://serverfault.com/users/86412/vladimir-blaskov)s [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/299305/test-virtual-host-configuration#answer-299310)